# Selenium Python: Flagging pages with specific span text

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I currently have a Selenium script that is running through a list of part numbers on a website and capturing some information such as product name (pulled from the page title).

I have noticed that some of the product is identified as "DISCONTINUED" (through a span) and so I would like to be able to capture that information so that I can ignore all of those products.

On the website in general, they denote these products through:

```
<span data*="">DISCONTINUED</span>
```

Any other products that are valid will not have this  information on it, and so in this case I want to ensure that the script doesn't crash and just captures a blank value.

I tried using:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//html/body/div/div/section/div/section/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/span/span[text()="DISCONTINUED"]')
```

However I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//html/body/div/div/section/div/section/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/span/span[text()="DISCONTINUED"]"}
```

I did make sure to use only a single part number that did indeed have a DISCONTINUED  on it.

I also did load up the page in dev tools and searched for that specific xpath and it did indeed highlight the proper section:

Searched:

```
//html/body/div/div/section/div/section/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/span/span
```

Highlighted:

```
<span data*="">DISCONTINUED</span>
```

What is the best way to do this? Also, I need to check to see how to include a blank value by default so that it will not crash when a current product is retrieved.

Comment: `(By.XPATH, '//html/body/div/div/section/div/section/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/span/span[text()="DISCONTINUED"]')` are you trying to locate the element with text _`DISCONTINUED`_

Comment: I am outputting the dataframe to an excel file with the information that is pulled from Selenium. So, I export out the part number and title. I would like to add whether or not it is Discontinued. That way any that are discontinued I can just remove from the data.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the HTML:

```
<span data*="">DISCONTINUED</span>
```

To locate the element with the text ***DISCONTINUED*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *xpath* and *`text()`*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='DISCONTINUED']")
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'DISCONTINUED')]")
  ```

---

Ideally to locate the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *xpath* and *`text()`*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='DISCONTINUED']")))
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *`contains()`*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(., 'DISCONTINUED')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: The first strategy was what I was trying and it didn't work. However, the second one using webdriverwait does yield an interesting result when there is a discontinued product such as

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="41240119cb3a4288a95877ae7644d9e2", element="72ab110b-3195-4f64-ab67-d275eff76ff4")>


However it will crash if the element doesn't exist...

Comment: @spitey _`I did make sure to use only a single part number that did indeed have a DISCONTINUED on it.`_: This answer address this concern. Nothing more or less. I can suggest n nos of improvements in the logic and the answer can be never ending.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to make it work with error avoidance.

```
try:
    discontinued = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//html/body/div/div/section/div/section/div/div/section/div/div/div/div/div/span/span[text()='ARCHIVED']")))
    discontinued = "CURRENT"
except:
    discontinued="DISCONTINUED"
```

Thanks again for the guidance on using waits instead of the find_element approach!